# How to generate navigation properties with EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, poco, texttemplate

I was previously using the [EF Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx) which included an option to *ReverseEngineerCodeFirst*, and in the process of switching to [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838).

Implementation:

```
        using (var db = new DbContext())
        {
            var user = db.Users
                .Include("MembershipType")
                .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
            . . .
        }
```

In using the POCO generator, I now get an error on the `.Include(...)` line:

> 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet' does not contain a definition for
>   'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In the generated context (and IContext):

```
    DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } // Users
```

In the context tt template, I changed instances of `IDbSet` to `DbSet` which fixed the issue, but I'm curious as to why, if `IDbSet` is an interface for `DbSet`, why doesn't `IDbSet` work?

Comment: I have plans to remove IDbSet from the generator and use DbSet instead. See http://efreversepoco.codeplex.com/workitem/89

Comment: I now use DbSet and have removed the use of the interface IDbSet from the generator. So you should be able to use your original `.Include` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all:

> System.Data.Entity.IDbSet' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method...

The [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679233%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) just doesn't have the method. I'm not sure why these method are not part of the interface. Maybe because `IDbSet` was introduced to facilitate mocking, and `Include` is a method that's very hard to mock.

Instead, you can use one of the the [`Include` extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.include%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) in the namespace `System.Data.Entity`. These method are defined on `IQueryable(<T>)`, which is an interface that `IDbSet` implements.

The same is true for another important method that's not in the `IDbSet` interface: [AsNoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237200%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). (Also hard to mock - in a sense - because tracking is hard to mock).

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe you are just missing the `using System.Data.Entity;` statement.

Answer (score 1):

IDbSet is a deprecated interface by Microsoft. The generator now uses DbSet instead.

Update to the latest EF Reverse POCO Generator [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838).

Source code is [here](https://efreversepoco.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the exact same problem reinstalling the Entity Framework.

```
Update-Package EntityFramework -Reinstall
```

The problem was the missing reference to EntityFramework.dll.